# Error following AWS Amplify DataStore documentation

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, datastore, aws-amplify-cli

When I follow the AWS [Amplify documentation for setting up DataStore using the CLI](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/getting-started/q/platform/js/#option-2-use-amplify-cli),
the following code

```js
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify'
import awsconfig from './aws-exports'
Amplify.configure(awsconfig)

import { DataStore } from 'aws-amplify';

try {
  const data = await DataStore.query(TestData);
  console.log("Data retrieved successfully!", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
} catch (error) {
  console.log("Error retrieving data", error);
}
```

where `TestData` is defined in my `schema.graphql` as described on the docs,  gives

```sh
Unexpected identifier '_awsAmplify'. Expected ';' after variable declaration.
at node_modules/metro-runtime/src/modules/HMRClient.js:106:4 in inject
at node_modules/metro-runtime/src/modules/HMRClient.js:115:2 in injectUpdate
at node_modules/metro-runtime/src/modules/HMRClient.js:183:20 in on$argument_1
at node_modules/metro-runtime/src/modules/vendor/eventemitter3.js:229:10 in emit
at node_modules/metro-runtime/src/modules/HMRClient.js:162:10 in _ws.onmessage
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket/WebSocket.js:229:8 in _eventEmitter.addListener$argument_1
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/_EventEmitter.js:135:10 in EventEmitter#emit
```

What does this error mean and how do I avoid it?

There is a cryptic and possibly relevant (and not quite grammatically correct) statement [in the documentation that](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/getting-started/q/platform/js/#initialize-amplify-datastore)

> When the `@aws-amplify/datastore` dependency is added to the project, the plugin is automatic initialized when you start using.

But no instructions to add that dependency (which is in any case case clearly available as part of `aws-amplify` as the successful import of `DataStore` demonstrates).

Explicitly adding both [`@aws-amplify/datastore`](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/getting-started/q/platform/js/#initialize-amplify-datastore) (ignoring warnings that it is already there) and [`amazon-cognito-identity-js`](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/migrating/#amazon-cognito-identity-js--is-required-if-you-use) as dependences does not fix the issue.

---

The same project works fine with GraphQL, e.g., if I replace the above with something like:

```js
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify'
import awsconfig from './aws-exports'
Amplify.configure(awsconfig)

const listTestData = `
  query ListTestData(
    $filter: ModelTestDataFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
  ) {
    listTestData(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
      items {
        id
        name
        categories
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
    }
  }
`
import { API, graphqlOperation } from 'aws-amplify'
API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listTestData, { filter: {},  limit: 50 })).then( f => console.log(f) )
```

---

In case it matters, I'm building using

```
eas build --profile development --platform ios --local
```

and running using

```
expo start --dev-client
```

Comment: try calling DataStore.configure({errorHandler: (error) => {alert(JSON.stringify(error);}});  before querying with Datastore.  That should set it up and let you know if there are any errors.  You c an also use that to do selective sync, where you only sync down data relevant to the client

Comment: @rleffler Using `DataStore.configure( {errorHandler: ( error ) => {alert(JSON.stringify(error)) } } )` I get `Error retrieving data [Error: Could not find a native getRandomBase64 implementation. Validate that amazon-cognito-identity-js is linked.]`.

Comment: Note that I **only** get that  the _first time I reload after adding the line of code_. In order to get it again I need to terminate the dev server and restart it (which strikes me as really really weird).

Comment: Explicitly adding both [`@aws-amplify/datastore`](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/getting-started/q/platform/js/#initialize-amplify-datastore) and [`amazon-cognito-identity-js`](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/migrating/#amazon-cognito-identity-js--is-required-if-you-use) as dependences does not fix the issue.

Comment: The configure method should only be called once, so that makes sense.  If you add selective sync functions it it, then sync gets called each time params change.  I do not know how to solve your current issue.  You might want to start a new question since you solved why it is not working

Comment: @rleffler How did I solve why it isn’t working?

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to help on that issue.

Comment: @rleffler Not following you. You said "You might want to start a new question since you solved why it is not working" Can you show me where have I solved why it isn't working?

Comment: I mean you need to solve why you are getting this now: Error retrieving data [Error: Could not find a native getRandomBase64 implementation. Validate that amazon-cognito-identity-js is linked.

Comment: @rleffler That has nothing to do with it.